# ActionController::RoutingError for existing route on staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have a Rails 5.1 api only app that I'm trying to post/update some data on.  Looking through the server logs, I see the error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/api/v1/users/1"):`

When running `rake routes` on the server, I'm seeing the route that's it's saying does not match:

```
api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format) /api/v1/users#show{:format=>"json"}
            PATCH  /api/v1/users/:id(.:format) /api/v1/users#update {:format=>"json"}
            PUT    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format) /api/v1/users#update {:format=>"json"}
            DELETE /api/v1/users/:id(.:format) /api/v1/users#destroy{:format=>"json"}
```

I just tested updating the data via Postman on my local server, and didn't have any issues.  Any idea what could be causing the issue?  Please let me know if more info would be helpful.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing `routes.rb` file?

Comment: The server should be restarted after each deploy.  To double check I ssh'd into the server and restarted it manually but still seeing the issue

Comment: Can you send a `PATCH` request to `/api/v1/users/1.json`?

Comment: sending the request to `/api/v1/users/1.json` is producing the same error

Comment: From where exactly you are calling `/api/v1/users/1.json` & can you please provide the exact link & params what you are passing to it ?

Comment: after digging into this a bit deeper, it appears Anurag Aryan was correct.  It looked like puma/rails was being restarted after the deploy, but after logging into the server, puma was not restarting and not picking up the new routes.